# Pulling data through based on the month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am attempting to build an excel spreadsheet where there are tabs at the bottom of the excel sheet for each of the 12 months - within the 'month' sheets pulls data from another sheet. It should only pull the data though if the data is within the same month.

i.e. 
"date received" in A column 
"Fees" in B column

Should I be using a pivot table? Or can I write a formula instead?

I started writing one but I don't know if I am going along the right lines at all!

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF(AND($A$1:$A$5>=$C$1,$A$1:$A$5<=$D$1),ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF(AND($A$1:$A$5>=$C$1,$A$1:$A$5<=$D$1),ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

Where A1:B5 is my table.
(column A is the date and B are the fees).
C1 and D1 is are the dates of the month (i.e. 1st October and 31st October).

What are peoples thoughts?

thank you

Comment: I don't quite get the problem here. Can you use some example values, pictures as well maybe of how it looks like and how you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you were on the right track with the pivot table idea. It would be, by far, the simplest way to achieve what I think you want: taking a master list of all dates & fees and producing a month by month summary of the data.  As a first step in C1 (and then copy down) put a formula to identify the month for the date in A

```
=INDEX($E$1:$F$12,MONTH(A1),2)
```

E1:F12 is a table where E1-E12 is 1-12 and F1-F12 is the 'name' of the month, i.e. "October"

Now, if you use A:C to create the pivot table you can summarize the fees by month.